# Black GRUB screen when booting into dual-boot of Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Help! I had a dual-boot of Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 on my computer. Last night I decided to "uninstall" Ubuntu. Rather than re-install the Windows MBR I decided to just edit GRUB to timeout at 0, with the default choice as Windows. I restarted my computer and it boot just fine into Windows. I removed all the Ubuntu partitions from Disk Management (being careful not to remove the partition with mount point /boot/efi) and reclaimed the unallocated space.

Today I turned on my computer and a black GRUB screen came up with the line "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions"

How do I boot in to Windows 8?!

Comment: The thing is as soon as I turn on my computer it goes to that black screen. How do I get to BIOS?

Comment: That's a hardware question and dependent on your hardware, so download and read your hardware's documentation...  [Esc], [F9] and [F12] are the most used keys is all I can say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally off-topic but the elephant in the room is missing: Boot Windows Media and re-install the Windows MBR?

Comment: Don't ask the same question to the same guy twice, please???  **:P  ;-)** See my other comment above... Oh, and if the above helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Is probably you deleted the folder who contained the grub bootloader. Sorry for my english. Try Boot Repair disk in a pendrive. You need to set off the Secure Boot.